# Overflow encountered in multiply in np.var while np.nanvar works just fine

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two 2D numpy arrays: `x` of type `float64` and `mask` of type `bool`. I want to find variation of every column in `x` only taking into account numbers defined by mask. Here's what I did:

```
np.var(x, axis=0, where=mask)
```

Unfortunately, it produced error:

```
FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in multiply
```

So I came up with this code:

```
x[~mask] = np.nan
np.nanvar(x, axis=0)
```

which works fine. However I'd like to avoid this approach as it requires me to do unnecessary assignment of nans which is a waste of time. I'd also like to avoid explicitly specifying `dtype` like this

```
np.var(x, axis=0, where=mask, dtype=np.float128)
```

since I consider the overflow error to be result of my poor code and `np.float64` should be more than enough for my task.
So please help me understand why seemingly equivalent first and second snippets yield such different results.

EDIT:
Important thing to note here is that I work in Jupyter notebook and that error seems to be reproducible only after kernel restart. Simply running the cell twice fixes it for some reason.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I think I know what the problem is, but it would be helpful if you showed how `x` and `mask` are created so I can confirm my suspicion.

Comment: My suspicion: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an intermediate calculation in `numpy.var` that operates on  *all* the input values, even those where `where` is False.  This can result in spurious warnings from `numpy.var`.  See the [numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20493) that I created about this.

Your `nan`-based work-around is fine.  It might also be sufficient to use `x[~mask] = 0` and then use `numpy.var` as you already are.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift your data to avoid an overflow without shifting the variance:

```py
np.var(x - np.max(x), axis=0, where=mask)
```

Comment: This helps but I still can't understand the difference. Also if I use `np.mean` instead of `np.max` the error is still present but a bit different:
```RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce```

Comment: You have some numerical instability in your data. It must come from some far right outliers, aka some values are very large and it makes some computations unstable. Please show some stats on the numbers you are processing (NaN fraction, quantiles, etc.)

Comment: `x` is initialized only in places where the `mask` is `True`, so I think this statistic is most relevant: `x[mask].max() = 47.465`, `x[mask].min() = 16.37673611111112` and as you can see there are no nans.